# MVC Dynamic Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url, routes

I would like to create dynamic urls that route to controller actions with an Id value. I've created the following route using a catch-all parameter

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "RouteName",                                                 
            "{id}/{*Url}",
            new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", id = "" }
        );
```

This works as expected and allows me to use the following Urls:

"http://website.com/1/fake/url/path" (1 being the id that gets passed to the action method)

Does anyone know a way to achieve it this way instead without creating my own http module?:

"http://website.com/fake/url/path/1"

Thanks - Mark

Comment: So you want an arbitrary number of segments before the id parameter?

Answer (score 1):

That's a really difficult one, for me anyway.

Given the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{*token}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", token = 0 });
```

Your controller and supporting classes would be something like this:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(IndexReqquestBinder))] IndexRequest request)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        ViewData["Message"] = String.Format("We're looking at ID: {0}", request.ID);

        return View();
    }
}

public class IndexRequest
{
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public IndexRequest(Int32 id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }
}

public class IndexReqquestBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public ModelBinderResult BindModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if ( null != bindingContext.RouteData.Values["token"] ) {
            foreach ( String v in bindingContext.RouteData.Values["token"].ToString().Split('/') ) {
                Int32 id = 0;
                if ( Int32.TryParse(v, out id) ) {
                    return new ModelBinderResult(new IndexRequest(id));
                }
            }

        }
        return new ModelBinderResult(new IndexRequest(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hellfire. not had a chance to try it yet but looks like just what i'm looking for.

Comment: Now ModelBinderResult is not available in System.Web.Mvc 2.0.0.0

Comment: I don't have time to test this, but can't you just:

  return new IndexReqeust(id);

and bypass the ModelBinderResult completely?

Answer (score 1):

Routes redirection is based on route entry in the route table. It must be in systematic way. For instance  if you have route as "customurl/id" after {controller}/{action}/{id}(default of mvc) when you will enter "customurl" in the url box it will take it as default route and no page found exception will occur. So if you wan to use custom route then first remove the default route. I do this like.

```
RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
                    if (routes["rname"] != null)
                    {
                        RouteTable.Routes.Remove(routes["rname"]);
                    }
                         routes.Remove(routes["Default"]);                           
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "newname",
                            url: url + "/{customId}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", customId = UrlParameter.Optional }
                            );

                        //default route value
                        routes.MapRoute(
                            name: "Default",
                            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest overriding of DefaultControllerFactory

```
> public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
>   {
> public override IController
> CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext
> requestContext, string controllerName)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 return base.CreateController(requestContext,
> controllerName);
>             }
>             catch (Exception exception)
>             {
>                 // collect route data
>                 string id = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
>                 string action = (string)requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
>                 // set full path as routing "page" parameter
>                 VirtualPathData path = requestContext.RouteData.Route.GetVirtualPath(requestContext,
> requestContext.RouteData.Values);
>                 requestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
> = path.VirtualPath; // or anything you need
>                 // use controller page by default
>                 controllerName = "MyController";
>                 // set basuc routing data
>                 requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
> = controllerName;
>                 requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
> = "index";
>                 // call base method to create controller
>                 return base.CreateController(requestContext,
> controllerName);
>             }
>         }
>}
```

And than just register this as default controller factory in global.asax.cs file

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyNameSpace.CustomControllerFactory ());
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // this already exists by default
        }
```

Comment: No. Don't take this approach. `IControllerFactory`s only responsibility is creating/resolving Controllers. Putting Route/Route parameters resolution logic into Controller Factory is a rough SRP violation.