# ASP.NET MVC page/subpage routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm try to figure out how to handle the following scenario. In general, i have a bunch of records in a table. All of these have ID and ParentID fields to form a tree.

```
Page1
 - Page2
 - Page3
Page4
 - Page5
 -- Page6
```

Now, i want my routes for Page3 and Page6 to be like `/Page1/Page6` and `/Page3/Page5/Page6` respectivelly. That is, i want to include all parents in the URL.

How to set my controller action/routing to achieve the above result?

Edit: Forgot to mention that the above structure will be dynamic - nodes can be added/deleted/change parent, etc.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296284/mvc-dynamic-routes) >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296284/mvc-dynamic-routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a wildcard match.

A possible route:

```
routes.MapRoute("SomeName", "{*Page}", new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" });
```

and in the action accept the string Page, and parse it manually, perhaps with a split?

This might also be useful: [URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. Saved my time.

Comment: @MichaelSamteladze np, that was nearly eight years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the controller name and action are fixed and not based on the url.

```
// place the more specific route first
routes.MapRoute("r1", "{parent}/{child}/{subchild}", 
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", parent = parent, child = child, subchild = subchild });

routes.MapRoute("r2", "{parent}/{child}", 
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", parent = parent, child = child });


public class PageController
{
    public ActionResult Index(string parent, string child, string? subchild)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use

```
routes.MapRoute("Page6", "Page3/Page5/Page6", new { controller = "Page6", action = "Index" });
```

or maybe using Regular Expression Routing

http://blog.sb2.fr/post/2009/01/03/Regular-Expression-MapRoute-With-ASPNET-MVC.aspx