# Is it possible to have dynamic actions in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I'm trying to build a file sharing website using MVC.  One of the nice to have features are short URL's - Typically in the format such as:

```
http://site.com/Rtravf2
http://site.com/XddsvgF
http://site.com/AaraEwq
```

The "actions" at the end of the URL's are in fact Ids which is used to download a file.  Urls in this format can all be mapped to the same action method in the home controller, called Download.

Here's the one and only route in my routes table

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What kind of route should i construct so those Urls can be mapped to the Download action on the Home Controller.

Currently getting a bunch of 404's (naturally!)

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019906/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-routes-and-action-links-with-arbitrary-depth

Comment: bobrock, tho perhaps a duplicate, only a single non-conventional answer given in reponse to that question, so question has validity i feel

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(null, // Route name
    "{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Download" }
);

routes.MapRoute(null, // Route name
    "Index/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```